# Numpy -complex modification of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a int16 numpy array such as:

```
 ([[ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],

   [ 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],

   [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],

   [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],

   [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

I'd like to modify this array so that every 1 with a 0 in the space directly below it becomes a 21. I'd also like to do this on multiple, much larger arrays. What is the fastest way to carry this out?

Comment: What do you want to happen to the bottom row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the last row is supposed to stay the same you can to the following.

```
sel = (A[:-1] == 1) * (A[1:] == 0)
A[:-1][sel] = 21
```

Here `A` is your matrix. The first line creates a masked array of size `(m - 1, n)` with `m, n = A.shape`.

Comment: @Preamble If an answer solved your problem, please don't forget to accept the answer. This shows other users, that they don't have to look for another solution.